# Confidence interval around a set of lines

Tags: confidence-interval, uncertainty

I ran an analysis that outputs an expansion path, which takes the form of a line. You can think of the line as a piecewise linear function. I'd like to take draws from the distribution of all variables in the analysis, resulting in a collection of 1000 lines. Is there a way to get uncertainty around the set of lines? I imagine it's easiest to get uncertainty in y given x. Ideally I'd also like to consider uncertainty in both y and x, as in orthogonal regression. Any ideas?